# not able to start a new basic React application in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am creating a basic React application in windows OS, everything went fine but when i am doing `npm start` the application is not getting loaded on `localhost:3000`. i am seeing the error `Cannot GET /`.

Here is the complete structure of my project -

`- webpack.config.js`

`- package.json`

`- index.html`

`- .babelrc`

`- src / index.html`

`- src / app.jsx`

**webpack.config.js** file -

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
    },
    ],
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
},
plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    hot: true,
},
};
```

**package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development --port 3000"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "webpack": "^5.24.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2"
  }
}
```

**index.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="./node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**.babelrc** file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

**src/index.js** file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
// hot reloading. It works by replacing a module of the application 
// during runtime with an updated one so that it’s available for instant use.
module.hot.accept();
```

**src/app.jsx** file

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <h1>
     React application
    </h1>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Note: when i am running `npm start` in command-prompt, i am not seeing `dist/` getting created.

Comment: Are you getting any error(s)?

Comment: @Manish no errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you created react project using old version of `create-react-app`. Try upgrading to latest version and create project using upgraded `create-react-app`.

Comment: No, I am not using create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Below are the changes you need to do

```
webpack.config.js
```

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, "./src"), "node_modules"],
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    hot: true,
    open: true,
  },
};
```

In file
src/index.js
replace

```
document.getElementById("app")
```

with

```
document.getElementById("root")
```

After making these changes, install `html-webpack-plugin` and start your app using `npm start`